# Selenium IDE: How to detect secure cookies on page loaded with http://?

Tags: firefox, cookies, selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Firefox 22 and Selenium IDE 2.2.0.

I have loaded a page in firefox using the HTTP protocol (not HTTPS). I know for sure that the page has set a secure cookie (as a result of an embedded AJAX request). I can verify this using the browser internal url chrome://web-developer/content/generated/view-cookie-information.html - because among other cookies that page shows a cookie like this:

```
Name    WC_AUTHENTICATION_5122759
Value   5122759%2cDKppXa7BAqnZ0ERDLb0Wee%2bXqUk%3d
Host    .testserver.dk
Path    /
Expires At end of session
Secure  Yes
HttpOnly    No
```

However, when I run assertCookie in the Selenium IDE I can only see the unsecure cookies. I.e. all cookies - except then one above - are detected by Selenium IDE:

Executing: `|assertCookie | glob:WC_AUTHENTICATION_* | |` yields this set of visible cookies:

```
[error] Actual value 'JSESSIONID=0000uCQdh2FZ0ZA8z-O5zcGoUtD:-1;
WC_PERSISTENT=lT8Z5tbkQrvLhNm%2bGyCj%2bh4yPAU%3d%0d%0a%3b2013%2d07%2d05+13%3a18%3a18%2e807%5f1373023098807%2d3048%5f10201%5f5122827%2c%2d100%2cDKK%5f10201;
WC_SESSION_ESTABLISHED=true;
WC_ACTIVEPOINTER=%2d100%2c10201; WC_USERACTIVITY_5122827=5122827%2c10201%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cy6bjcrZgvCVe5c52BBKvcItxyF5lLravpDq9rd9I0ZmRfRNxcC2oG13Eyug3kKgbtLOHVLxm9T76%0d%0a%2fGJFLp5bOrkPoNqmc38TIr%2fO7eU%2fbd7Mfny2kQg7v6xGweYoRkXYgAEz91rH0QavFhlOjpd12A%3d%3d;'
did not match 'glob:WC_AUTHENTICATION_*'
```

So does anyone know how can I use the Selenium IDE to verify the presence of secure cookies on a page loaded with http:// (not https://) ?

Comment: if you own the server code, when the server is under test, you can send the secure cookie to insecure connection.

Comment: I own (or can control) both server and client side of the code - Unfortunately I have to maintain the correct combination of secure and insecure cookies - because the purpose of the test is to ensure, that thes is in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, what you are doing is breaking the specifications. A secure cookie is suppose to be only available if the connection is secure. Hence, if you are connecting with HTTP, you can't see it.

However, if this is just on your test machine (not your end user), you can modify the response from the server using Fiddler. With Fiddler, you can program something like, if you see this cookie, add another cookie, or strip the secure flag.

EDIT:

Some background information about Selenium and cookies:

Selenium works through the browser with JavaScript as part of the page. Because it is essentially a part of the page, it has to follow all the same rules as the page. This means that it still has to abide by the security rules on cookies. A secure only cookie can only be read on a secure connection, thus Selenium cannot read a secure cookie if it's not on a secure connection.

The place where HTTP request comes in is that cookies are a part of the HTTP header. Both the request (from the browser) and the response (from the server) have an HTTP header. Cookies are present in both.

You want to verify if the server has set the cookie, so you want to inspect the HTTP response from the server for the presence of the cookie. Because of security restrictions, however, you cannot from Selenium. These security restrictions are enforced by the browser. All reputable browsers enforce these policies, since without these policies, the end user's credentials will be easily compromised.

This is where Fiddler comes in. Fiddler inspects the HTTP data at a lower level, before the browser gets to it. Thus, you can use Fiddler to manipulate the data before it gets to the browser to give some kind of indication that the cookie was present.

Comment: So - if I understand you correctly, you are saying that e.g. Selenium's verifyCookiePresent is reading the browser cookies via an HTTP request?

Comment: @tbsalling I've added a lot more explanation on how this works.